# how to redirect various independent domains to various wordpress category pages

Tags: linux, .htaccess, redirect

basically I have approx 30 various domains all pointing to the one IP, and in my conf file all these domains are pointing to the one wordpress folder.

But my wordpress site has various categories, and a page for each one. The various domains match the categories...
e.g. I have

www.whattodoinlimerick.com

www.whattodoinroscommon.com

and in my site I have...

http://www.whattododirectory.com/category/limerick/

http://whattododirectory.com/category/roscommon/

At the moment those two domains load up the homepage of the site, is there a way I can redirect them to that particular category page?
301 redirect doesnt work as thats specific to just paths of the original domain as oppose to independent URLs, any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Do you have defined a virtual host for each domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have them all being hosted under the same document root, you can try adding these rules **to the top** of the htaccess file that's in the document root. You want to make sure they're above any wordpress rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?whattodoin([^.]+)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.whattododirectory.com/category/%2/ [L,R=301]
```

For 301 redirects. Since this is a *redirect*, the browser's URL address bar changes to the target URL. If you want to internally rewrite on the server side, replace the last line with:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ /category/%2/ [L]
```

Or worst case:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.whattododirectory.com/category/%2/ [L,P]
```

depending on how wordpress is setup. Neither of the those will change the URL in the browser's address bar.